# I want to make a query, retrieve several columns from several tables

Tags: php, mysql

I want something in PHP-mysql

I want to make one query, retrieve several or all columns from several tables

**Example**

```
query 1: "SELECT * FROM table1"
query 2: "SELECT * FROM table2"
query 2: "SELECT id,name FROM table3"
query 2: "SELECT num,num2 FROM table4"
```

And so on If you want to add more .

I want to combine all these queries in a single query .

**Note:** All queries  doesn't associated with some, and also I do not want a problem occurs if the table is empty .

***any helper here to help me***

Comment: what you need is some way to join the data together for example a column that exists in both tables that is common to each table

Comment: @Rob - There is no relationship between the tables, Therefore can not be used (join)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a UNION ALL statement, but you have to specify a coherent (same) structure of output columns for each select. For example:

```
SELECT (columnA1, columnA2, null, null) FROM tableA
UNION ALL
SELECT (null, null, columnB1, columnB2) FROM tableB
```

and so on.

Comment: the number of columns differ between tables, Therefore can not be used (UNION)

Comment: No, you can. Only you have to specify default values (i.e. null) for columns that are in one table but not in the other (see the example).

Answer (score 1):

You could use UNION, but for that all the queries must have the same number of collumns in the select. You can solve it by add dummy values to select like this: SELECT col1,col2, '' as dummy

EDIT:
you cant use * if tables dont have the same number of collumns. What you can do is this:

Suppose your table1 has 3 cols and table2 just 2 cols.
You would do the following:

```
select col1,col2, col3 from table1
UNION
select col1,col2, '' from table2
```

Comment: (SELECT * FROM pic_files) AS files UNION (SELECT * FROM adv) AS adv UNION (SELECT * FROM pic_cat) AS cat UNION (SELECT * FROM users) AS user UNION (SELECT * FROM groups) AS group ------- but not work

Answer (score 0):

You need is some way to join the data together for example a column that exists in both tables that is common to each table

eg Accomodation database of sudents

**Accomodation_table**
Accomodation_ID | Accomodation_Name

**Student Table**
Student_ID | Student_Name | Accomodation_ID

Accomodation_ID is the common field

the query would look like this

```
Select a.Accomodation_Name, b.student_name
from Accomodation_table a, Student_Table b
where a.Accomodation_ID = b.Accomodation_ID
```

Comment: There is no relationship between the tables, Therefore can not be used (join)

Comment: @Lion King thats a shame, it would be very easy in a relational database - I would seriously consider making your database relational - there are many benefits!

Comment: I know , relational is Useful but i don't need to relationships between the tables in my script this time

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you want to combine these tables. Most likely you need to **JOIN** them:

See: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

In case if you want just show them as one table with the same number of columns you can check **UNION** operator:

See: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Comment: There is no relationship between the tables, Therefore can not be used (join). and also the number of columns differ between tables, Therefore can not be used (UNION)

Comment: You need to create fake columns in your tables by selecting empty/zero/NULL values, so the number of columns is the same in all tables and equals to max number of real columns from one of the real tables.

Answer (score 0):

If there are **no** relationships between the tables then you are effectively asking for the following

```
select *
from table1, table2, table3, table4
```

which is called the Cartesian join and is normally to be avoided. The number of rows in the result set will be the number of rows in table1 * the number of rows in table2 * the number of rows in table3 * the number of rows in table4!

Normally a Cartesian join occurs when one forgets to add the relationship between tables but you seem to want this deliberately.